# TinyMCE V5 - Toolbar labels displayed vertically inside CSS grid

Tags: css, tinymce

When TinyMCE v5 is place inside a CSS grid, the toolbar labels display vertically.

It seems like "width:auto" isn't being applied, but I'm unable to find a way to fix it.

I'd be grateful of any suggestions to resolve this.

[image: Screenshot]

```css
.hg_grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "header header" "navigation main" "footer footer";
  grid-template-columns: 200px minmax(0, 1fr);
  column-gap: 20px;
  grid-template-rows: 100px 1fr 50px;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
.hg_grid header {
  grid-area: header;
  background: #cccccc;
}
.hg_grid footer {
  grid-area: footer;
  background: #cccccc;
}
.hg_grid main {
  grid-area: main;
  background: #e0e0e0;
}
.hg_grid aside {
  grid-area: navigation;
  background: #b7b7b7;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>TinyMCE - Test</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
     <script src="https://cloud.tinymce.com/5/tinymce.min.js?apiKey="qagffr3pkuv17a8on1afax661irst1hbr4e6tbv888sz91jc"></script>
    <script>
        tinymce.init({
            selector: '#mytextarea'
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body class="hg_grid">
    <header>
        <div>
            HEADER TINYMCE TEST
        </div>
    </header>
    <aside>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">NAV</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </aside>
    <main>
        <h1>TinyMCE Inside CSS Grid Test</h1>
        <form method="post">
            <textarea id="mytextarea">Hello, World!</textarea>
        </form>
    </main>
    <footer>
        <p>FOOTER</p>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's the above example on codepen:
https://codepen.io/dezertdezine/pen/QYrLKV

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem, fixed it by adding this to my css:

```
.tox {
    white-space: nowrap!important;
}
```